# Switching OpenGL to perspective mode on top of a half rendered orthographic scene?

Tags: opengl-es, orthographic, perspectivecamera

We have a mostly 2D game that runs in orthographic mode, but one part shows a 3d model that is  rendered in between the other 2D objects.  How can I switch to perspective mode, render that model, then switch back to render the other objects in orthographic mode?

Kudos if you can show how it's done in OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this isn't exactly specified question. Are you want more views? Or you want to have 2D background, 3D game objects, 2D gui. If you want this, then:

- render fullscreen background
- set viewport to position=obj.pos-obj.size/2, size=obj.size, render object
- render 2D gui

Or you want something else?

EDIT:

Here's little code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,w,0,h,near,far);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(pos.x,...);

DrawQuads();

//if you want to keep your previus matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90,width/(float)height,0.001,1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(pos.x,...);
glRotate(-45.0f,1,0,0);
glTranslate(0,0,distance from object);
glRotate(90.0f,1,0,0);
// or use gluLookAt
// 0,0,1 - if you want have z as up in view
// 0,1,0 - for y
//gluLookAt(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,cam.x,cam.y,cam.z,0,0,1);

glScale(object.width/model.width,...);
DrawModel();

// Restore old ortho
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: I'm rendering several quads in orthographic mode in the background (sprites) after this I need to render a 3d model in perspective mode, then after that i need to render some more sprites in the foreground.

It's not just a full screen background.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make the code example.  I didn't realize you could push a projection matrix.  Also the rotate/translate code was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, "just do it"

- set your projection matrix as ortho
- set your modelview for 2D objects
- render your 2D objects
- set your projection matrix as projection
- set your modelview for 3D objects
- render your 3D objects

... and this can go on again an again

- and swap buffers.

If you KNOW the order of your objects as you seem to do, you can also clear the z-buffer between each render.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous posts, and I think more general case is like 3D object and 2D gui.
Just for re-emphasis. : )

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective( 45.0f, (GLfloat)s_width/(GLfloat)s_height, near, far);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
// render 3D object
glUseProgram(modelProgram);
glSetUniformMat(glGetUniformLocation(model.mvp, "mvp"), mvpMat);
glBindVertexArray(model.vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.size);
glUseProgram(0);


glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
// draw GUI
renderGUI();
```